# Serialize different types of users in PassportJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, serialization, deserialization, passport.js

I have two local strategies for two different types of users: Students and Teachers. I am having trouble trying to login because my serialization is not working properly.

I have two models, Student and Teacher. Both have their separate collections, student and teacher with similar schema. Both have similar functions:

```
module.exports.getStudentByUsername = function(username, callback){
    var query = {username: username};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getStudentById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
        if(err) throw err;
        callback(null, isMatch);
    });
}
```

My two local strategies are:

```
passport.use('student-local', new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        Student.getStudentByUsername(username, function(err, student){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(!student){
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown Student'});
            }
            Student.comparePassword(password, student.password, function(err, isMatch){
                if(err) throw err;
                if(isMatch){
                    return done(null, student);
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
                }
            });
        });
    }));

passport.use('teacher-local', new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        Teacher.getTeacherByUsername(username, function(err, teacher){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!teacher){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown Teacher'});
        }
        Teacher.comparePassword(password, teacher.password, function(err, isMatch){
                if(err) throw err;
                if(isMatch){
                    return done(null, teacher);
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
                }
            });
        });
    }));
```

My two logins are:

```
router.post('/loginStudent',
passport.authenticate('student-local', {successRedirect:'/users/student', failureRedirect:'/login',failureFlash: true}),
function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});

router.post('/loginTeacher',
passport.authenticate('teacher-local', {successRedirect:'/users/teacher', failureRedirect:'/login',failureFlash: true}),
function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

My serialization and deserialization are:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    if(Student.findOne({username: user.username}).length != 0) {
        done(null, user.id);
    } else if(Teacher.findOne({username: user.username}).length != 0) {
        done(null, user.id);
    }
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    if(Student.getStudentById(id)){
        Student.getTeacherById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    } else {
        Teacher.getTeacherById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    }
});
```

I know my serialization is wrong and that is why I am not being able to get this to work. When I tried with only one type of user and with the simpler serialization I found in the passport documents, my login was working fine.I am new with node and passport so any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your serialization doesn't work, because the query for finding the teacher / student is actually async and you are treating it as sync.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    Student.findOne( { username: user.username }, function( err, student ) {
         if ( student ) {
              // user is student
              done( null, user.id );
         } else {
              Teacher.findOne( { username: user.username }, function( err, teacher ) {
                   if ( teacher ) { 
                        // user is teacher
                        done( null, user.id );
                   }
              } );
         }
    } )
} );
```

This should work, although I'm not sure why you are doing to lookup for the type of user. You can just do :

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
     done(null, user.id);
} );
```